# MongoDB - Lookup match with condition array of object with string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections "datasets" and "users".

I tried to lookup `datasets.assignedTo = users.id` that's working fine. Also, I want to match the field of `datasets.firstBillable >= users.prices.beginDate` date field are matched to get the current index price value. And also check `users.prices.endDate` is less than or equal to `users.prices.beginDate`.

For example:

> cgPrices: 45

https://mongoplayground.net/p/YQps9EozlAL

**Collections:**

```
db={
  users: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Aravinth",
      prices: [
        {
          beginDate: "2022-08-24T07:29:01.639Z",
          endDate: "2022-08-31T07:29:01.639Z",
          price: 45
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Raja",
      prices: [
        {
          beginDate: "2022-07-25T07:29:01.639Z",
          endDate: "2022-07-30T07:29:01.639Z",
          price: 55
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  datasets: [
    {
      color: "braun, rose gold",
      firstBillable: "2022-08-24T07:29:01.639Z",
      assignedTo: 1
    },
    {
      color: "beige, silber",
      firstBillable: "2022-07-25T07:29:01.639Z",
      assignedTo: 2
    }
  ]
}
```

**My current implementation:**

```
db.datasets.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "as": "details",
      let: {
        assigned_to: "$assignedTo",
        first_billable: "$firstBillable"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$id",
                    "$$assigned_to"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$gte": [
                    "$first_billable",
                    "$details.prices.beginDate"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$lte": [
                    "$first_billable",
                    "$details.prices.endDate"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "details": 0,
      "cg": {
        $first: {
          "$first": "$details.prices.price"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Output i needed:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "assignedTo": 1,
    "cg": 45,
    "color": "braun, rose gold",
    "details": 0,
    "firstBillable": "2022-08-24T07:29:01.639Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "assignedTo": 2,
    "cg": 55,
    "color": "beige, silber",
    "details": 0,
    "firstBillable": "2022-07-25T07:29:01.639Z"
  }
]
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/YQps9EozlAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerns:

1. You should compare the date as `Date` instead of string, hence you are required to convert the date strings to `Date` before comparing.
2. In `users` collection, `prices` is an array. You need to deconstruct the array to multiple documents first before compare the date fields in `price`.

The query should be:

```
db.datasets.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "as": "details",
      let: {
        assigned_to: "$assignedTo",
        first_billable: {
          $toDate: "$firstBillable"
        }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$id",
                "$$assigned_to"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$prices"
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$gte": [
                    "$$first_billable",
                    {
                      $toDate: "$prices.beginDate"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$lte": [
                    "$$first_billable",
                    {
                      $toDate: "$prices.endDate"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "details": 0,
      "cg": {
        $first: "$details.prices.price"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PnkFRd-WdVB)

Comment: this is working fine. but without pipeline its possible?

Comment: Probably yes, but more complex. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GyKxoVhZuVA)